# Non-density of invertible elements in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N}_0)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-and-monoids, banach-algebras

Consider the Banach algebra $\ell_1(\mathbb{N}_0)$ (with convolution / Cauchy product of series). I am looking for an elementary proof of the fact that the group of invertible elements in this algebra is not dense.

If one wishes to use some hammers, here is a way to do so. Call this algebra $A$; it is not too hard to show that $A$ is semi-simple. Thus the Gelfand transform $g\colon A\to C(\Phi_A)$ is injective and has dense range. However $\Phi_A = \overline{\mathbb D}$ and it is well known that invertible elements in $C(\overline{\mathbb D})$ are not dense.

> Q1. Is there a more elementary way to see this (preferably that would work for the real scalars too)?
>
> Q2. Is there a characterisation of semigroups $S$ for which invertible elements in $\ell_1(S)$ are (not) dense?

Comment: Do you at least know a series you expect not the be in the closure of invertible elements?

Comment: @YCor, I'd say $\delta_1 =(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: I tried with this one :)

Comment: Hi Tomek, I happened to be revisiting this question and unless I am misreading something your claim that $g:A \to C(\Phi_A)$ has dense range is incorrect. So even the approach with hammers doesn't seem to do the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1 can be answered with the following result.

> An element in the boundary of the invertible group of a unital Banach algebra is a topological divisor of zero.

I must confess I remembered the statement but not the proof, but it can be shown using elementary arguments related to the fact that the invertible group is open. It should be in e.g. Allan's book on Banach algebras (since it is in the lecture notes which evolved into that book) and probably also in Bonsall and Duncan. If I have time in the next day or two I can include the argument here.

<s>Regarding Q2: if $S$ is a (discrete) group with polynomial growth, then I **think** the invertible elements should be dense in $\ell^1(S)$, using the above criterion and Corollary 1.9 in this paper of Tessera the results of https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2010.07.014 (sorry for being sketchy right now, please remind me if I don't update this answer within the next couple of days)</s>

<s>I have a feeling that Q2 is open even when S is a discrete solvable group of exponential growth, but I have not kept up with progress in this area for a while. The case of commutative monoids might be tractable</s>

Comment: Thanks Yemon, this is what I needed, I think. As for your remark on groups with polynomial growth, take $S = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Then the spectrum of $\ell_1(S)$ is two-dimensional and so the invertible elements are not dense in $C(\mathbb{T}\times\mathbb{T})$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TomekKania Oops - my mistake. I was thinking of the dichotomy "invertible, or is a tdz", but that doesn't address Q2.

Comment: For context, $x$ topological divisor of zero means there exists $y_n$ not tending to 0 such that $xy_n$ tends to zero. Clearly $\delta_1$ is not a topological divisor of zero (since multiplication by $\delta_1$ is norm-preserving) and is not invertible (its image is the set of sequence vanishing at 0).

Comment: @YCor, I hope that you don't mind that I accept Yemon's answer but it really offers an elementary and scalar-choice-independent proof.

As for Q2, I don't think it is really tractable. (However, some particular cases are still welcome).

Comment: Here's a proof of the main claim, using for convenience ultrafilters. Let $z_n$ invertible converge to $z$. I fix an ultrafilter $u$. If $\lim_u|z_n^{-1}|=\infty$, then it immediately follows that $z(z_n^{-1}|z_n^{-1}|)$ tends to zero, so $z$ is a topological divisor of 0. Otherwise, this implies that the sequence $(z_n)$ defines an invertible element of the ultrapower $A_u$ (the set of $u$-bounded sequences in $A$ with $u$-limit norm modulo being of norm zero). Since $A$ is closed in $A_u$ and since the inverse map is continuous, it follows that the inverse belongs to $A$; this is $z^{-1}$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for this nice presentation of the argument. Could you perhaps expand on the final sentence? (It is certainly not true that if a Banach algebra A is closed in a larger algebra B, then all B-invertible elements of A are A-invertible; so one is using particular properties of the inclusion $A\to A_u$)

Comment: No I use that $z_n^{-1}\in A$ for all $n$ and $z_n^{-1}\to z^{-1}$, so $z^{-1}\in A$. No special property of the inclusion.

Comment: For the future reference, this is Theorem 14 on p. 13 in Bonsall and Duncan.

Comment: Well more simply $\|a^{-1}-b^{-1}\|\le\|a^{-1}\|\|b^{-1}\|\|a-b\|$. This shows that if $(\|z_n^{-1}\|)$ is bounded then $(z_n^{-1})$ is Cauchy so we conclude without even using ultrafilters.

Comment: @YCor yes I find this last part more convincing, and it is closer to the "classical" argument that Tomek refers to. (One cannot assume $z^{-1}$ exists before proving that it exists, so you cannot use $z_n^{-1}\to z^{-1}$, but as you point out in your comment, one uses $z_n\to z$ and $(z_n^{-1})$ being Cauchy)

Comment: In the argument using ultralimit, $z^{-1}$ indeed exists in the ultralimit, namely the element represented by $(z_n^{-1})$ is an inverse for $z$ (provided $\lim_u\|z_n^{-1}\|<\infty$), so it does work in this way (that's the point of ultralimits: defining elements without caring any convergence). But I agree the Cauchy argument is more elementary: it's just that this was the way it came to my mind.

Comment: I think we are in "violent agreement" :) Basically, one needs the fact that if a sequence of A-invertible elements converges to an element of A that is B-invertible, then this element is A-invertible. But to prove this is essentially the same as the claim in question; and the Cauchy argument is what does it.

Answer (score 4):

For Q1:

Every $f=\sum a_nz^n\in A$ induces a continuous function $\hat{f}$ on the closed disk of radius $1$ and $f\mapsto \hat{f}$ is a continuous operator (for $\ell^1$-norm $\|f\|=\sum|a_n|$ on the left and sup norm $g=\sum_{|z|\le 1}|g(z)|$ on the right), which in addition is multiplicative.

The for $u(z)=z$, it is standard ($*$) from differential/algebraic topology that every $g$ close enough to $\hat{u}$ (the identity of the closed disk) in the supremum norm has a zero. It follows that $u$ (which is indeed $\delta_1=(0,1,0,\dots)$ is in the interior of the set of non-invertible elements of $A$. The same argument works for $z^n$, $n\ge 1$.

($*$) indeed if $g$ is close enough to the identity then it is homotopic to the identity, and if $g$ does not vanish, then we can deduce a homotopy from the identity of the circle to a constant map.

Comment: This is basically the Gelfand transform argument :) It is nice though that one does not need the property "range of the Gelfand transform is inverse-closed", which to my knowledge needs something like Gelfand-Mazur, hence relies on complex scalars.

Comment: Yes, but well, I wrote everything without reference to any technology, at an undergraduate level (and it works for real scalars).

Comment: Well, let us not debate "undergraduate level" (diff/alg top). The argument I referenced only uses submultiplicativity of the norm and the formula for  $(1-x)^{-1}$, together with some basic ability to manipulate convergent sequences in Banach algebras; and it works just as well for noncommutative algebras. FWIW, I do like the Gelfand transform argument!

Comment: @YemonChoi, but the Gelfand-transform argument also requires complex scalars, doesn't it, as real sequences may be mapped to complex, non-real functions.